Tumor segmentation task : Accuracy curve on validation data starting from a high point
Does anyone know why does the accuracy for the validation set is starting from a high point instead of zero like the training set ? could it be due to class imbalance because the tumor size is small compared to the background ?
enter image description here
enter image description here

I think this is just a matter of y-axis scale. Train starts from 0.982 and valid starts from 0.996. Not a big difference imho.
